# Second Program Window

Tags: java

I am trying to make a plugin for a Minecraft server where I would like to open up a second console window to display other information to the owner.

However I am struggling to find the information I need. I have found hundreds of tutorials on how to create a second program but I want to display it from within another console window.

I have also seen creating a GUI through Swing but I'm not really after a GUI window (unless it's my only option).

Is there a way of opening a second program console window where I can write what I like to it? (basically an information display panel)

Comment: Something GUI based is your best option. The "console window" has nothing to do with your application, it's the operating system providing something to interact with stdin and stdout. You only get one set of "standard" streams, after all.

Comment: @Phoshi Ok thanks, that was the information i wanted to know to make a decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to create a separate GUI window using swing.

The best way I have found in minecraft is to create a separate class which will allow you to keep all the code in one place, inside create your methods for drawing the window and methods for adding information to it.

I would then declare it in the main file as a global variable creating a function for getting the instance. then you can get it from any listener/command handler.

dont forget to close the window when the plugin stops/is restarted otherwise the window will remain while the minecraft server is running.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I did. I turned it into an API in its own separate plugin so that other plugins could make use of it.